# Ruby random number generator is skewed when called from initializer

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to model the Monty Hall problem where a user is asked to select one of three doors, then is offered to switch the door. I'm looking for a random variation of choices, which should be in the range of 50% switched vs. 50% stayed.

```
class Scenario
  def initialize
    # switched?
  end

  def switched?
    @sw ||= [true, false].sample
  end
end

results = { switched: [], stayed: [] }

1000.times do
  s = Scenario.new

  if s.switched?
    results[:switched].push(s)
  else
    results[:stayed].push(s)
  end
end

puts results[:switched].count
puts results[:stayed].count
```

When I inspect the results hash, in this example, the array counts tend to be about 500/500 as expected.

However, if I uncomment `switched?` in the initializer method, the results tend to be split about 750/250. The results are still random-looking (e.g. 738 to 262), but they are always skewed to be an incorrect solution to this problem.

I have also tried using other mechanisms like `rand(2).zero?` to generate the data, but the same problem occurs.

Why or how could calling this memoized function in the initializer cause the random variation to be so far, yet consistently off?

Comment: Can you show us the `initialize` method in both cases? Are you using `||=` in an initialize method?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You've given a great explanation of the behaviour, but an incomplete code sample of how you generated it - therefore I don't know how to **reproduce** your problem.

Comment: At a guess though, is the problem not that you are calling `switched?` **twice**, and the variable will be memoized if and only if it's `true`? If you randomly choose `false`, then the `||=` gets re-evaluated; therefore `true` will be chosen 75% of the time.

Comment: Tom, you nailed it. I was thinking the conditional assignment operator only re-assigns on nil, but you're right it's on false as well. 50% the first pass, and 50% the next means about 75% will be switched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ruby, all values other than `nil` and `false` are considered "truthy".

When you call `foo ||= bar`, `bar` will be evaluated if and only if `foo` is "falsey" - i.e. equal to `nil` **or `false`**. (Or if it's undefined!)

In your code, you have the following:

```
def switched?
  @sw ||= [true, false].sample
end
```

So, the `@sw` variable will memoize the result of the method call **only if `[true, false].sample` returns `true`**!!

What this means, then, is that if you call `switched?` multiple times, you are giving the `@sw` variable "multiple attempts" to randomly choose `true`.

If you call `switched?` once, there's a 50% chance of it being `true`. Call it twice, and there's a 75% chance (as you observed). Call it 3 times, and there's a 87.5% chance. And so on.

In order to memoize a potentially `false` value, you need to be a little more explicit with the syntax - e.g.

```
def switched?
  return @sw if defined?(@sw)
  @sw = [true, false].sample 
end
```

You can now call `switched?` multiple times, safely. It will remember its first result, even if `false`, and not re-calculate it.